# java.lang.NullPointerException: expected receiver of type android.app.ActionBar, but got null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-emulator, navigation-drawer

I have an app using a Navigation Drawer which works fine on phones. But it does not work on an emulator. If I click on any item on navigation drawer . The emulator simply hangs.

**This is what I get in Logcat:**

```
08-01 00:11:08.342: W/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb(2745): Couldn't set home-as-up indicator via JB-MR2 API
08-01 00:11:08.342: W/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb(2745): java.lang.NullPointerException: expected receiver of type android.app.ActionBar, but got null
08-01 00:11:08.342: W/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb(2745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 00:11:08.342: W/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb(2745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-01 00:11:08.342: W/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb(2745):     at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.setActionBarUpIndicator(ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.java:55)
08-01 00:11:08.342: W/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb(2745):     at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplHC.setActionBarUpIndicator(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:130)
08-01 00:11:08.342: W/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb(2745):     at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.setActionBarUpIndicator(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:372)
08-01 00:11:08.342: W/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb(2745):     at android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:230)
08-01 00:11:08.342: W/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb(2745):     at com.places.logic.NavDrawerActivity.onPostCreate(NavDrawerActivity.java:199)
08-01 00:11:08.342: W/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb(2745):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
```

The line where it shows `NullPointerException` is

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
```

MY mDrawwerToggle initialisation code :

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
           //     getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: Can you add some code? It looks like you're getting a Null Pointer Exception in NavDrawerActivity.java at line 199

Comment: Can you add the bit of code where you initialize mDrawerToggle? That's where you're getting the NPE

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `onPostCreateMethod()` and instead try this

```
mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
});
```